# Trigger JavaScript mousemove without moving mouse but get mouse coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, mousemove

I'd like to register a `mousemove` callback and immediately trigger that callback with the current mouse x/y position.  Currently I'm doing this:

```
$('body').mousemove(hoverFunction).mousemove();
```

But `hoverFunction`'s event receives undefined values for pageX and pageY as documented.  Is there a clean way I can handle this besides having a `mousemove` callback that updates a global mouse position variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a `jQuery.Event` object and set `pageX` and `pageY` properties on it directly. Then trigger this event on `$(document)`. [See this StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772222/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-mousemove-and-get-event-pagex-event-pagey/14483616#14483616)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').bind('mousemove',function(e){   
    hoverFunction(e);
});

$(function(){
    $('body').trigger('mousemove');
});
```

Comment: I think this still has the same problem.  The event that should be passed in on your first line (change `function()` to `function(e)`) doesn't have `e.pageY` or `e.pageX` defined.