# Is there a way to trigger mousemove and get event.pageX, event.pageY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events

So, like the question specifies, is there a way to trigger a `mousemove` event in jQuery which also sends the mouse coordinates to the event Object?

So far my code can trigger the `mousemove` using the `.trigger(event)` function but the `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` are undefined.

Comment: Once thing that you could do is save the event data from the last real mousemove event, then when you trigger it programmatically reuse it if no new event data exists. If real mousemove events aren't fired, that means the mouse didn't move, so the eventData from the last real mousemove should have the current position still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe it possible to get the mouse coordinates on demand via JavaScript / jQuery; however if you bind the position to a global var you can then access them at anytime throughout the document like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $().mousemove(function(e){
      window.xPos = e.pageX;
      window.yPos = e.pageY;
   }); 
});
```

for a less CPU intensive option, you can add a timeout, although you trade performance for a slight delay in knowing where the mouse is:

```
function getMousePosition(timeoutMilliSeconds) {
    $(document).one("mousemove", function (event) {
        window.xPos = event.pageX;
        window.yPos = event.pageY;
        setTimeout("getMousePosition(" + timeoutMilliSeconds + ")", timeoutMilliSeconds);
    });
}
getMousePosition(100);
```

You should now be able to access the window.xPos and window.yPos from anywhere in the document using either solution without needing to trigger a faux event.

Comment: -1 this doesn't address the question, which involves a manually triggered event.

Comment: I know how to get the coordinates of the mouse by binding mousemove on an object. But say the mouse is not moving, but I want to use the trigger function in jQuery to trigger a virtual mousemove and still get the coordinates.

Comment: @geossj5 - If you're tracking the mouse already, and the mouse is no longer moving, then surely whatever the last recorded coordinates were will still be the case...?

Comment: @JamesAllardice - Ya that is what I have now, but I thought there would be a more efficient and less CPU intensive way.. Thanks for the insight though.

Answer (score 39):

You need to set `pageX` and `pageY` directly before triggering the event. To set these properties, make a `jQuery.Event` object.

```
// create a jQuery event
e = $.Event('mousemove');

// set coordinates
e.pageX = 100;
e.pageY = 100;

// trigger event - must trigger on document
$(document).trigger(e);
```

[See it in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPgnp/).

Comment: This does not work as jQuery will ignore the pageX and pageY parameters when trigger is called.

Comment: What leads you to this conclusion? Check out [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPgnp/).

Comment: I agree, this method has been the best for me, quite easy to define the event yourself and just change the pageX/pageY props yourself

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question.  You can do:

```
$('.someClass').mousemove(function(event){
    console.log(event.pageX);
    console.log(event.pageY);
});
```

Now, whenever the mouse moves over `someClass`, it will register the xy cordinates.  Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YA4a2/) to see it in action and the jquery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/).

Comment: I know how to get the coordinates of the mouse by binding mousemove on an element. But say the mouse is not moving, but I want to use the trigger function in jQuery to trigger a virtual mousemove and still get the coordinates.

Comment: How are you moving the mouse with Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move a mouse if that is what you're asking. But you could call a function with whatever context and arguments you want. E.g.:

```
function foobar(e)
{
  this.className = 'whatever'; // this == element
}

someElement.onmousemove = foobar;

var obj = {whatever:'you want'};
foobar.call(someElement, obj); // calls foobar(obj) in context of someElement
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I know your problem. You're trying to query the mouse position programmatically. Perhaps you have code something like this:

```
$(document).one('mousemove.myModule', function (e) {
    // e.pageY and e.pageX is undefined.
    console.log('e.pageY: ' + e.pageY + ', e.pageX: ' + e.pageX); }
        ).trigger('mousemove.myModule');
```

Then you're absolutely right. The properties pageY and pageX on the event object won't be defined. Actually, there's a hole lot of stuff in the event object that won't be there, not just `.pageY` and `.pageX`. Could be some bug in jQuery. Anyways, just don't chain that call to trigger **and** trigger the event on $(window) instead. Don't ask me why it works though but for me it did:

```
$(document).one('mousemove.myModule', function (e) {
    console.log('e.pageY: ' + e.pageY + ', e.pageX: ' + e.pageX); } );

// Now e.pageY and e.pageX will be defined!
$(window).trigger('mousemove.myModule');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with, that doesn't inolve you setting global variables.  The click event will still capture the coordinates, so you can pass that event to your mousemove.

```
$(element).click(function(e){
  $(element).trigger('mousemove',e);
});
```

Then, that event object will be the second argument in your mousemove function; the first being either the actual mousemove event or the jQuery created event.

```
$(element).mousemove(function(e,clickEvent){
  if typeof e.pageX === 'undefined' e = clickEvent;
  // or if you prefer, clickEvent.pageX;
});
```