# Mouse movements in WebdriverJs not registered by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webdriver, webdriver-io

In my testing environment I'm using the unofficial webdriverjs from http://webdriver.io/ for testing my frontend. Even though I took a look in the source https://github.com/camme/webdriverjs I was unable to define mouse movements properly.

Using

```
client.moveTo(undefined, 200, 200, function () {
    client.buttonDown (function () {
        //print location of click
    });
});
```

gives me a click at x: 200; y : 200. My problem is that no mouse movement is registered (using `$('...').on('mousemove', func {});` )

Is there any way to send mouse movements in such a way that they are recognized as mousemove events?

Regards

Comment: Selenium doesn't trigger mousemove events while setting the mouse cursor via `moveto`, though it could be get implemented in future. We will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I already got JQuery on the client side I solved the problem now by sending respective Javascript code which triggers customized events like for example shown here: [Is there a way to trigger mousemove and get event.pageX, event.pageY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772222/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-mousemove-and-get-event-pagex-event-pagey) (third answer)