# Simulating mouseover event in Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I am trying to trigger `mouseover` event which does not seem to work very well in Safari and Chrome in Mac:

```
$(".footer img#image").trigger('mouseover');
```

I also tried this javascript code snippet:

```
var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
event.initEvent("mouseover", true, true); 
document.getElementById("#image").dispatchEvent(event);
```

However this also does not seem to work very well. Does anyone know a reliable way to get this to work in Safari and Chrome in Mac?

Comment: Are you trying to trigger the mouseover event to simulate a hover (and its styling), or are you trying to merely trigger the event?

Comment: You can't "simulate" hover, but you can trigger the custom event handlers you have added.

Comment: @DanielApt I am trying to trigger `mouseover` event on an image.

Comment: remove the `#` from the `document.getElementById` call, it's not jquery :), you should use the plain ID attribute value.

Comment: I don't understand why nothing is happening, as I am able to trigger the ```mouseenter``` event and am able to capture it, see http://jsfiddle.net/r0adz34z/

Comment: Maybe you are triggering the event before you have added the event listeners? Have you verified that an actual ```mouseenter``` does trigger the handler?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new jQuery event and adding pageX and pageY to it:

```
var element = $("div.target");
var mouseover = $.Event("mouseover");
mouseover.pageX = 100;
mouseover.pageY = 1000;
element.trigger(mouseover);
```

Native Javascript:

```
<h1 onmouseover="style.color='red'" onmouseout="style.color='black'">Mouse over this text</h1>
```

[Also a link to native events (which should work for all browsers)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/event.initMouseEvent)

I've seen similar posts to this with both on will try and find \ post links if possible.

Hope this helps!

[I know its for mousemove but this post might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772222/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-mousemove-and-get-event-pagex-event-pagey)