# Trigger mouse move event with custom coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

How do I trigger a mouse move event with custom coordinates in jQuery?

I tried the following:

```
canvas1.trigger('mousemove',{pageX: window.width/2 , pageY: window.height/2});
```

and I also tried running this:

```
canvas1.trigger('mousemove',{pageX: 800 , pageY: 800});
```

However the pageX and pageY seems to be undefined in the event.

I've called this inside a mouse move event:

```
console.log("Fake mouse move event called successfully! X:", e.pageX, "& Y:", e.pageY);
```

And I didn't move my mouse at all so I could only see the fake event.

This is the result I am getting:

`Fake mouse move event called successfully! X: undefined & Y: undefined`

I also tried this with `clientX` and `clientY`, and the problem persists..

Has anyone got an idea to how to fix this problem? Have no idea what is going on here.

Thanks, help much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

```
canvas1 = $("#canvas");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14483616/6377043).
Here is how you can create an event and customize its properties in jQuery.

```
// create a jQuery event
e = $.Event('mousemove');

// set coordinates
e.pageX = 100;
e.pageY = 100;

// trigger event - must trigger on document
$(document).trigger(e);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either... What do you mean by must trigger on document. Do I have to do $(document).trigger(e)?

Comment: you do not need to trigger on the document, unless you want to fire the handler you attached on the document.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this might help then, (editing the answer)
[How to simulate a click by using x,y coordinates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277369/how-to-simulate-a-click-by-using-x-y-coordinates-in-javascript)

Comment: I am triggering a custom mouse move event and I would like to specify custom coordinates in that event. Sorry if you misunderstood my question.

Comment: Not seeming to work, probably because it clicks the elements. I would also like to trigger the event onto a canvas. When the event is triggered I would  like a mouse move event to be called, and e.pageX + e.pageY will be a custom coordinate. Thanks for the help.