# With CasperJS,how to make mouse operation in order to make the effect of "dragging"?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, drag

I use "http://104.238.150.223:8888" in order to test it, which is a html that we can paint with mouse on it, and my code is as follow:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var mouse = require('mouse').create(casper);

casper.start('http://104.238.150.223:8888',function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.wait(2000,function() {
        this.mouse.down(0,0);
        this.mouse.move(40,40);
        this.mouse.move(60,40);
        this.mouse.down(60,40);
    });
    this.capture('test.png');
})
```

But it doesn't work, there is nothing in the drawing board T_T

Answer (score 0):

#### Native event

Native dragging is not possible with PhantomJS (CasperJS is built on top of it), because each `casper.mouse.*()` call actually starts a new mouse action and "resets" the previous one. The press status of any mouse button is not kept between the calls. That has something to do with how [PhantomJS' `page.sendEvent`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html) works, which handles all the user actions through CasperJS (emphasis mine):

> The first argument is the event type. Supported types are 'mouseup', 'mousedown', 'mousemove', 'doubleclick' and 'click'. The next two arguments are optional but represent the mouse position for the event.
>
> The button parameter (defaults to left) specifies the button to push.
>
> **For 'mousemove', however, there is no button pressed (i.e. it is not dragging).**

#### Synthetic event

You may try to trigger synthetic events with the [available DOM APIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html) inside of `casper.evaluate`. You would need to

- find the element on the page that is actually responsible of capturing those UI events and
- [trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14483616/1816580) the appropriate events on that element: 1 x `mousedown`, n x `mousemove` and 1 x `mouseup`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I make it to use mousemove, mousedown and mouseup separately in the chrome console in the way in [trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772222/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-mousemove-and-get-event-pagex-event-pagey/14483616#14483616) , but still fail to combine them T_T